# Primefaces: selectionMode multiple/ set Value of Checkbox

Tags: jsf, checkbox, datatable, primefaces

I´ve implemented a datatable in JSF with a column with a attribute selectionMode="multiple".
Everything is working so far.

Is there a way to manipulate the value of the checkbox? I want to set the checkbox on the first load to checked or to unchecked, depending on a specific value.
The function i have implemented (in java) returns already true or false, but i need to set the checkboxValue to that value. What do i have to do to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the checkbox value through the `value` attribute like for any other component. See the DataTable demo with multiple selection:

[DataTable - RadioCheckbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the booleanCheckbox example on Primefaces i can set the value like you said: 
<p:selectBooleanButton value="true">. 
But how can I set the attribute "value" in the column?
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />
In the primefaces showcase all values are set to unchecked as default. There is no value attribute inside the column

Comment: Sure, because the selection values are stored in `selection="#{tableBean.selectedCars}"/>` (on the primefaces example). If the `selectedCars` list is empty, there are no selected values when the dataTable is initialized.